# Delete Items from text file and replacing items in vb language by visual studio 2012

Tags: vb.net

I need methods that help to delete items by form, from text file and replace these items by form to change it in the file using VB.NET

I used this:

```
Dim book() As String = File.ReadAllLines("book.txt")

While book(i) <> book.length 

    book(i).replace(old_vlaue , new_value) 

    i = i + 1

End While
```

This method didn't change the contents in file :\ ?????

any help please ??

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: a) you are trying to change the string read FROM the file, not the file itself; you'd have to rewrite the file to change the file b) you are not using Replace correctly.  Read the syntax provided in Object Browser and Intellisence: `Returns a new string in which all ...`